# how to I get IIS to point to its localhost 5003 so it is accessible for a app which is running inside a container

Tags: windows, docker, iis, containers, localhost

I have a api application hosted in Docker .net core runtime 7.0 image.
The api application is accessible on the Windows Server 2019 VM via localhost:5003/swagger.

The same VM has IIS running multiple sites, e.g. scuser.easyfast.com.
This existing IIS site has certificates and security set up and is hosting and running the production site.

I need to bind scuser.easyfast.com/swagger to (on the same host) localhost:5003.

I’m used to go into IIS, basic settings, and point to a physical path. My question is how to I get IIS to point to its localhost 5003 so it is accessible from swagger url mentioned? There is no physical path to a file structure anymore.

I tried reverse proxy and urlrewrite please give me solution on this.thanks

Comment: According to your description, I couldn’t understand your requirement clearly, do you mean when you access `scuser.easyfast.com/swagger` the content displayed on the target page is localhost:5003? If so, you can try to bind the local ip address to scuser.easyfast.com in the host file, and then set swagger as the default page, If I misunderstand your requirement, please post more details information about your requirement.

Comment: sorry for the misunderstaning of question which i asked but its resolved yesterday only bdw thanks for the reply and the solution is here ,Since i have already has a site with the desired site binding to process HTTP requests at scuser.easyfast.com. Then i install ARR and add reverse proxy rules to forward /swagger to localhost:5003, and that's how i solve, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/extensions/url-rewrite-module/reverse-proxy-with-url-rewrite-v2-and-application-request-routing